# Difference between port number and process id?

Tags: networking, operating-system, port, computer-science

- Process id(aka PID) uniquely identifies a process running on a computer.
- Port number uniquely identifies a process running on a computer in a network.

Why can we not use PID instead of port number for connecting to a program (along with IP and protocol) running on a computer in a network?

Can someone explain how exactly the port number and PID work?

Answer (score 0):

Process Id is number that uniquely identify process on computer at any point of time.

Port number and IP address allows identify source or destination of packet.

Inside of sockets stack there are exist table of mapping's processes to open sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Process id is the id of a running program.

whereas:

- A socket is like a telephone (i.e. end to end device for communication)
- IP is like your telephone number (i.e. address of your socket)
- Port is like the person you want to talk to (i.e. the service you want to order from that address)